# Can Asp.Net support streaming of 320kbps mp3 files?

Tags: asp.net, iis, mp3, media-player, audio-streaming

I have a piece of my site being built for me that works like this... when you click a song, the song loads in the player and plays it.

I'm being told by the guy who's developing it for me that Asp.Net does not support 320kbps files, so that's why the player isn't working. This seemed a little ridiculous so I did some research on it and couldn't find anything that says so:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28VS.95%29.aspx

He found this on that page:

> 24 bit audio will return silence.

But that's under the WMA section, not the MP3 section, I can't even tell if they're 24 bit or not anyways... The only info I have is that the songs are 320kbps and they're all .mp3 files. I can provide more info if you tell me where to look. Please let me know why he would be saying that these files can't be streamed... he says he's tried 128kbps and it worked, but that these are incompatible.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

> I'm being told by the guy who's
>   developing it for me that Asp.Net does
>   not support 320kbps files, so that's
>   why the player isn't working.

You're right, he's wrong. That page is irrelevant.

Asp.net doesn't care -- doesn't know! -- what's inside the file. If the connection doesn't overtax the available bandwidth, you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a static file and not a dynamic one, ASP.NET will never even see it. All references to static files are handled by IIS, without involving the ASP.NET runtime.

However, by default static files aren't streamed. Instead, they are sent at the maximum speed that the connection will support.  If you want true streaming, you will need to add an appropriate plug-in to IIS, or use something like Windows Media Server.